# VIM in shell triggers d key but GVIM work ok

Tags: linux, vim, shell

I have strange problem with my vim. In shell when I edit file my VIM triggers (**probably**) d key (running `vim test.txt`). When I press j he deletes first 2 lines. Everything works ok when i run without my .vimrc file (so I think that is my fault) or when I run gvim.

- [My .vimrc file](https://bitbucket.org/exu/vim/raw/master/vimrc)
- [My .vim directory](https://bitbucket.org/exu/vim/src) (vimrc file mapped as symlink in system)

Comment: Try `:verbose imap j` to see where `j` could have been remapped. Also I've read recently that mappings using `<Esc>` could cause weird problems. What is your `$TERM`?

Comment: romainl write this as answer i'll accept it. I've in my vimrc ` nnoremap <esc> :noh<CR><esc>` after deleting this line everything is ok, thanks alot.

Comment: Ok, there you go. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:verbose imap j` to see where j could have been remapped.

Also I've read recently that mappings using `<Esc>` could cause weird problems.

By the way, what is your `$TERM`?